# where can i find magento ajax image loading gif?

Tags: magento-1.9

Where can I find magento ajax image loading gif? How can I replace the default existing magento ajax loading gif?

Answer (score 4):

The loading icon is actually an animated gif located in **images/opc-ajax-loader.gif**.  In Magento 1.9.0.1 for example it is located in:

> /skin/frontend/rwd/default/images/opc-ajax-loader.gif

The loading image is in quite a few .phtml template files as well as a few css files.  You can see a list of all of the files referencing it by searching the codebase for **"*opc-ajax-loader.gif*"**.

The easiest way to override it universally will be to place an image of the same name in your custom template directory called **/images/opc-ajax-loader.gif**

So for example:

> /skin/frontend/mypackage/mytheme/images/opc-ajax-loader.gif

Make sure you don't overwrite the file in one of the default themes as this could get overwritten in a future upgrade.  It would be a bit easier to change this out if the element used a css rule for that image so you could override but the above would be the fastest way to change the loader gif out.

**Changing loader in the Admin**

If you are changing the loader in the admin and would like to remove the "Please Wait..." loading text probably the easiest way would to be doing it through translation.
You would add the following to a translation csv file:

**app/design/adminhtml/default/**<your custom admin theme>**/locale/en_US/translate.csv**

> "Please wait...",""

If you don't have a custom admin theme I would suggest creating a custom module to add your translation to the admin theme.

Two resources that may help you out:

> http://blog.belvg.com/editing-magento-translate-csv-file.html
>
> http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-your-own-translations-to-custom-modules

Adding custom styles to the css can also help you change the look of the loader.

Comment: Well answered. Consider adding formatting to make it a bit more legible.

Comment: Thanks @philwinkle - I updated the formatting to make it a bit more legible.

Comment: i did overwrite the gif file. but the animated gif is completely different from what is being loaded on the front end

Comment: @Haya Double check the new animated gif is in the active theme folder and make sure to clear your browser cache.  Also if you have a custom theme that is using a different filename for the animated gif you will want to inspect the element and see what the path to the image shows. If that is the case then use the above procedure in the answer and use the new path to place the animated gif.

Comment: I was able to change it. But only partial. Please see before and after. The box and please wait text doesn't seem to go away. Before http://monosnap.com/image/3c9HyTIJukZnuKzZwLB5cxN8ptcZnZ  after http://monosnap.com/image/rdvDARzkOmbn5m4oLfzrwgMin01I6W

Comment: It looks like you may be changing the loader in the admin?  I added some additional information on changing the "Please wait..." text in the admin.  You can apply the same to the frontend as well if you have an ajax loader on the front end.

Comment: i was able to remove the please wait text. but what about the box itself and background colour. how can i remove?